# Arrange data in a CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

I have a PS script that queries AD for the members of an OU. Works great except the output comes out with the user information first and then the group name. I would like the group name in the first column. I have tried moving the `$Group.Name` around in the `foreach` loop. Did not help.

Here is the code so far.

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=mygroup,OU=AllGroups,DC=***,DC=local"

$Table = @()

$Record = @{
  "Group Name" = ""
  "Name" = ""
  "Username" = ""
}

foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
  $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Recursive # | select name,samaccountname

  foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers) {
    $Record."Name" = $Member.Name
    $Record."UserName" = $Member.SamAccountName
    $Record."Group Name" = $Group.Name
    $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
    $Table += $objrecord
  }
}

$Table | Export-Csv "D:\logs\AlfrescoUsers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Try `$Table | Select-Object Group Name, Name, Username | Export-Csv "D:\logs\AlfrescoUsers.csv" -NoTypeInformation`

Answer (score 2):

Make the property hashtable an ordered hashtable:

```
$Record = [ordered]@{
  "Group Name" = ""
  "Name" = ""
  "Username" = ""
}
```